# Animation inside a fragment that is in viewpager

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a problem. As said i have ViewPager with 5 Fragments inside. On the last fragment i have two relative layouts with some widgets inside. On button click i have animations that changes relative layouts to visible.

My problem is that when i scroll back the view that is gone becomes visible all by himself... Anybody experienced something similar???

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    private FragmentAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome_activity);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private ViewPager pager;
    private Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ViewPager p) {
        super(fm);
        this.pager = p;
        this.mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new ScreenWelcome(pager, this);
        case 1:
            return new ScreenTutorial1();
        case 2:
            return new ScreenTutorial2();
        case 3:
            return new ScreenTutorial3();
        case 4:
            return new ScreenTutorial4();
        case 5:
            return new FlipAnimationFragment();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 6;
    }
```

```
public class FlipAnimationFragment extends Fragment{
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flip_animation, container, false);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        sign_up = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutSignUp);
        log_in = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutLogIn);

        create_account_page = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCreateAccount);
        log_in_page = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUpLogIn);

        log_in_page.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!pressed){
                    pressed = true;

                    layout.startAnimation(flip);
                }

            }
        });
        create_account_page.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!pressed){
                    pressed = true;

                    layout.startAnimation(flip);
                }

            }
        });
}
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        flip = new FlipAnimator(sign_up, log_in, 240, 400);
}
```

Comment: becomes visible by himself? -> relativelayout is already there without the buttonpress + animation

Comment: First layout is visible. I press the button, animation starts and second layout is visible (first is gone). Then i start swiping to left and, for now reason the layout which state is gone becomes visible. That the problem...

Comment: Probably their will be a newly created fragment. Your viewpager is by default configured to keep 3 pages in memory (the one your looking at - to the left - to the right). You should track which fragments are instantiated and destroyed by debugging/logging your pageadapter. (getItem() and destroyItem())

Comment: Another tip: fragments should use an no arguments constructor! during configuration change the framework will use the no arguments constructor to reinstantiate your fragment. If you want to pass something to you fragment use setArguments(Bundle bundle) function

Comment: I didn't know for the arguments...great tip. For now my orientation is portrait. But i don't have fragment to the right. I didn;t try to look for a pageadapter...i give it a try... Thanks...